Tensorflow Keras ProgbarLogger does not accept arguments
In Python 3.10.14, and with tensorflow version 2.16.1, the following minimum working example produces an error:
import tensorflow as tf
pb = tf.keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger(count_mode='steps')

the error being: TypeError: ProgbarLogger.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'count_mode'
But the documentation for ProgbarLogger (also here) says that this argument exists.  To check if it was a typo, I also tried the positional argument version:
import tensorflow as tf
pb = tf.keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger('steps')

Also gets an error: TypeError: ProgbarLogger.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
This is the most up to date version of tensorflow, if I didn't mess up the install command somehow, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Regardless, in the second documentation page I linked above, the version number is the same as mine (which I got by running pip show tensorflow).
It may be relevant to tell you that after opening python, the following information is displayed:
Python 3.10.14 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar 21 2024, 16:20:14) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

And just after running import tensorflow as tf, it prints:
2024-04-08 10:38:02.032301: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-04-08 10:38:21.403223: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.

And as a last note, all of this is being run from within VS code, but I don't think that's relevant.

Downgrading tensorflow to version 2.15.0 solved this issue for me. (Supported Python versions: 3.9–3.11)
pip install tensorflow==2.15.0

